# Use of datetime timedelta with numpy array as an input

Tags: python, numpy, datetime, timedelta

I have a line of code (below) which converts a UTC time to  local solar time (LST) (both datetime objects), using timedelta.

```
time_lst = time_utc + timedelta(hours=lon*12/180)
```

The formula requires the longitude (lon). My issue is that lon is a numpy array of float64 and so this won't currently work with the timedelta method. How can I get my 'lon' array to work with timedelta?

Comment: `(lon*12/180).astype('timedelta64[H]')`might do the job

Comment: Hmm. (lon*12/180).astype('timedelta64[h]') returns an array of 3's, which seems like we might be on the right track if that's 3 hours. But not sure where the rest is (i.e. the fractional hour, or minutes..)

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure what is going on because (lon*12/180).astype('timedelta64[s]') gives the same output as (lon*12/180).astype('timedelta64[h]')...

Comment: The first is a number of seconds, and the second is a number of hours. What level of precision do you want here?

Answer (score 0):

This will compute a `timedelta64[s]` corresponding to the right number of hours. You can use a smaller time unit than `s` if you want more precision.

```
timediff = lon*12/180 * np.timedelta64(1, 'h').astype('timedelta64[s]')
```